# Ionic 2: how to get error from created Observable?

Tags: angular, ionic2, observablecollection, reactive-programming, reactive

I have defined following function:

```
 searchProducts(searchText: string){
     return Observable.create(observer => {
           return this._http.get(this._global.baseUrl + "/products/search/searchProducts?search=" + searchText)
            .map(res => res.json())
                .subscribe(data => {
                        observer.next(data);    
                        observer.complete();

                },
                err => {
                    return Observable.throw(err); // this statement is called
                    });
        });   
  }
```

here is the calling statement:

```
this.productService.searchProducts(this.searchItem)
                .subscribe(products => {
                  console.log(products);
                },
                err => {
                 console.log(err); // this statement is not getting called
                });
```

**Problem:** When getting products from server, the subscribe data callback is called but when getting error(say for **network connection timeout or network error**),err callback is not getting called.

I'm completely exhausted with trying or finding solution, Could somebody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http.get() method return an observable object. You don't have to encapsulate your result inside a new Observable.
So you can just write your get service like this :

```
searchProducts(text:string): Observable<Array<Product>> {
    return this.http.get(this._global.baseUrl + "/products/search/searchProducts?search=" + searchText)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Then, to handle error :

```
protected handleError(error: Response): Observable<any> {
    var errorJson = error.json();
    if (errorJson) {
        console.error(errorJson.message);
        return Observable.throw(errorJson.message || error);
    }
    return Observable.throw(error);
}
```

Comment: Thanks... I already implemented this thing and it works but I'm curious to know why nested observables are not working. I wasted whole day about finding the issue.

Comment: because your error comes before subscribing. Try to throw your error outside of subscribe method : .map().catch().subscribe()

Comment: removed extra curly brace (typo), I had .subscribe() with 2 args